# How to use internet in raspberry pi 3 when it is remotely connected to my laptop via wifi router?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

I’m newbie and I’ve put my best effort to solve this and the following are the steps I've followed,

1. Installed, RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH PIXE
2. /etc/network/interfaces,
   /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf & /etc/dhcpcd.conf are as mentioned & attached.

/etc/network/interfaces,

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

wpa_supplicant.conf,

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="YOUR WIFI NETWORK NAME"
        psk="YOUR WIFI PASSWORD"
        proto=WPA
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=TKIP
        group=TKIP
        id_str="YOUR WIFI NETWORK NAME"
}
```

dhcpcd.conf,

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.103/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

After doing this, I’ve connected raspberry pi to wifi and can remotely access it using VNC player. But in VNC player, I could not connect to any website but I can access my router using 192.168.0.1 (my router). Also, when I take my cursor to wifi symbol over top right corner it shows me that it is associated to my router and configured with ip I’ve mentioned.

I think I’m missing something but I don’t know what it is.

P.S: if I connect using LAN and share my wifi then it works. Also, if I type “ifconfig wlan0” then “inet addr” field has an address beside it and "ifconfig" shows me connected router.

Comment: Try adding Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8) to your dhcpcd.conf like so: static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using obsolete settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`. If you are going to put `dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces` there is no point modifying `dhcpcd.conf` because `dhcp` disables `dhcpcd`.

To fix see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

NOTE this has nothing to do with your problem (whatever this is - your question is unclear; "connected RSP to wifi" what is a "RSP"?).

If you get rid of the static IP address and connect the Pi to your router (via Ethernet or WiFi) and let the router do its job everything should work.

Comment: Here, RSP = Raspberry PI. Okay, I will try to solve it using the link you have mentioned. Thanks :)